# mount LVM volume

Tags: lvm, openstack

I have installed openstack cinder module. Everything works great. but i want to mount a volume in order to see its contents.

I typed lvscan command on cinder storage computer. I can see my volume list.

```
 ACTIVE            '/dev/cinder-volumes/volume-XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXX-XXXX' [1.00 GiB] inherit
```

but when i type

```
 mount /dev/cinder-volumes/volume-XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXX-XXXX /mnt
```

i get this error message

```
  mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/cinder--volumes-volume--XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,
  missing codepage or helper program, or other error

  In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
  dmesg | tail or so.
```

Is it because volume is already mounted by openstack instance ? What should i do for mounting or reading/writing data in this volume ?

Here is the lvdisplay command result:

```
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/cinder-volumes/volume-d6dc111d-5496-4e5b-a554-e781691b0611
  LV Name                volume-d6dc111d-5496-4e5b-a554-e781691b0611
  VG Name                cinder-volumes
  LV UUID                nTlThd-770h-Y0kq-iIRD-DiCg-2ugv-lPwyUo
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time block1, 2016-11-03 09:56:56 +0100
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                1.00 GiB
  Current LE             256
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:0
```

Comment: Please provide output of lvdisplay

Comment: Cinder only provides block storage to instances; it *does not* create a filesystem for you.  So if you haven't previously run `mkfs` on that volume, it doens't have a filesystem and can't be mounted.

Comment: Thanks but how can i see what is inside a cinder volume ?